# Trying to fetch data from excel in flutter

Tags: excel, flutter

[image: example file]
as you can see above i am trying to fetch the data from the excel by using their name but it's always saying Student not found in the Excel file
here is the full code:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> getStudentScores(String name) {
    var studentData = <Map<String, dynamic>>[];
    var excel = Excel.Excel.decodeBytes(fileBytes);

    for (var table in excel.tables.keys) {
      for (var row in excel.tables[table]!.rows.skip(2)) {// Start from the third row

        if (row[0] == name) {// Check the second column for the name

          print('a');
          var scores = row
              .skip(2) // Skip name and potential blank
              .map((value) {
                if (value is int) {
                  var subject = excel.tables[table]!.rows[1]
                      [row.indexOf(value) + 2]; // Get subject from header
                  return {"subject": subject, "score": value};
                } else {
                  return null;
                }
              })
              .toList()
              .cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
          studentData.add({"name": row[0], "scores": scores});
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return studentData;
  }
```

and i am accessnig it like this

```
onTap: () async {
                        var studentData = await getStudentScores(_name.text);
                        if (studentData.isNotEmpty) {
                          // Display retrieved name and scores
                          setState(() {
                            texts = ['${studentData[0]["name"]}'];
                            result = studentData[0]["scores"]
                                .map((score) => score["score"])
                                .toList(); // Extract scores
                            number = result.length; // Number of subjects
                          });
                        } else {
                          // Handle "Student not found" scenario
                          print("Student not found in the Excel file.");
                        }
                      },
```

I tried everything that i know